# Generating no edges from adjacency matrix

Tags: r, igraph

When calling `graph_from_adjacency_matrix()` from `igraph` I am getting no edges at all.

```
library(igraph)

set.seed(42)

# data = read.table("sequences_distancematrix.out", row.names = 1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
data = read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/UWt56tfh", row.names = 1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)


dismat = data.matrix(data)

# build the graph object
network <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(dismat, mode = "undirected")
```

However upon inspection of the network there is no edges:

```
> print_all  (network)
IGRAPH f4f6666 UN-- 46 0 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
```

I though it was perhaps because `igraph` would not accept doubles below 0 so `x10` everything in the matrix but go the same result

The distance matrix: https://pastebin.com/UWt56tfh

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: seems you need `weighted=TRUE`, or use `graph_from_adjacency_matrix(dismat > 0, ...)`, which is surprising, although been a while since I read the help `?graph_from_adjacency_matrix`

Comment: Would this also matter that I am using an distance matrix ?

Comment: As it is a distance matrix you likely want a weighted graph

Comment: I _think_ the relevant bit could be "*If it is NULL then an unweighted graph is created and the elements of the adjacency matrix gives the number of edges between the vertices.*" . If you r weight is  < 1  it seems as if it gets rounded down to zero, hence no edge ? maybe?

Comment: That seems logical. I am getting edged now so will filter to only shows those above a certain distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you want to have weighted edges:

```
(network <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(dismat, mode = "undirected", weighted = TRUE))
```

- If you want to have unweighted edges:

```
(network <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(dismat > 0, mode = "undirected"))
```

Comment: I am using a distance matrix generated from mash distances of genome sequences. @user20650 suggested weighted would be more appropriate  which given my understanding of weighted networks it correct?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you tried to multiply everything by 10, but that worked for me.

```
library(igraph)

data <- read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/UWt56tfh", 
                  row.names = 1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE) 

dismat <- data.matrix(data)
network <-  graph_from_adjacency_matrix(dismat*10, mode = "undirected")
print_all(network)
```

Comment: multiplying by a constant really is hit or miss and could result in unexpected results. Try `m = matrix(0.1, 3, 3); diag(m) = 0 ; g = graph_from_adjacency_matrix(K* m, mode = "undirected") ; E(g)` for various `K` e.g. 10, 15, 25. It seems to take the `floor` of the double to round down to the nearest integer, and this integer determines the number of edges between two nodes.